# "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found", Ubuntu 22.04, Broadcom Wireless Drivers [14e4:4331] (rev 02) MacBook Pro

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, broadcom, adapter

I used to have another version of Ubuntu on my old MacBook Pro and one day Wi-Fi disappeared with the "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" in the Settings. I tried to follow various options found on different forums and it didn't help. I installed Ubuntu 22.04, but the problem is the same.

I enclose [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCIMm.jpg) for the commands: `lshw -c network`(photo 1), `lspci` (photo 2), `sudo dmesg |grep b43`, `rfkill list all`, `grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*`(photo 3), `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`(photo 4).

[image]

I downloaded a file from here (http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/?C=D;O=A), but I don't know where I should locate it.

upd. after `sudo dmesg | grep b43` - the following [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iubly.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste from the terminal and put the text into the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Download this package to your desktop: http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/b43fw_508.tar.gz

Right-click it and select ‘Extract Here.’ Now, from the terminal:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware
sudo mkdir b43
sudo cp ~/Desktop/b43fw_508/b43/*  b43
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

Once your internet is restored, let’s install the latest versions of the firmware:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install –reinstall firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: thank you for readiness to help! the thing is that I don’t have an Internet connection on the laptop, so should I download it to a USB? and where should I put it on the laptop then?

Comment: Use a USB key and place it on your desktop.

Comment: Thank you loads! I did it and the software has been upgraded, yet the result is the same: "no Wi-Fi adapter found".. :( in the Terminal, all of that "sudo" lines should have been as different commands after "usr/..", right?

Comment: so, I connected my phone as a "wired Internet" (and downloaded directly to the laptop, placing it on my desktop). The thing is that when this whole problem with adapter happened, the line "Wi-Fi" disappeared from Settings. So, I should search for it. It's written "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found. Make sure you have a Wi-Fi adapter plugged and turned on". if it helps somehow :(

Comment: or maybe the problem was in the amount of spaces used? can it be a problem in Linux syntax?

Comment: I assume you have the b43 firmware installed as above. May we see: `sudo dmesg | grep b43`

Comment: I have edited the post and added the answer!

Comment: seems like the changes weren't saved :( now they are (: